# Pass link tags in links using Aws SES api

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am using AWS SES api to send emails. I have used configuration set for email tracking in which the destination type is blank; I am using SES default domain and I have selected click event. Now I want to track all links but perform action to some particular links.

To do this I tried adding ses:tags attribute all  tags as described in the documentation here:
[sending metrics link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/faqs-metrics.html#faqs-metrics-clicks)

`<a ses:tags="product:book;genre:fiction;subgenre:scifi;type:newrelease;"   href="http://www.amazon.com/…/">New Releases in Science Fiction</a>`

But these tags neither show up in the link nor in the click event data sent by aws.

**UPDATED**

Click event data:

```
"click" : {
        "ipAddress" : "1.1.1.1",
        "userAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0",
        "link" : "http://www.facebook.com",
        "linkTags" : "",
        "timestamp" : "2021-02-11T03:32:54.848Z"
    }
```

**NOTE**: I am not using Cloudwatch as event destination in configuration set.

Can someone guide me what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

[It's only possible to track clicks in HTML emails.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/faqs-metrics.html#faqs-metrics-clicks)

[How can I monitor the opens, clicks, and bounces from emails that I send using Amazon SES?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ses-email-opens-clicks/)

[Sending email using the Amazon SES SMTP Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/examples-send-using-smtp.html)

I used `configset` to send the events to `SNS` topic and subscribed my lambda to `SNS topic`, below are the results:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "gopkg.in/gomail.v2" //go get gopkg.in/gomail.v2
)

const (
    Sender     = "sender@example.com"
    SenderName = "senders name"
    Recipient  = "recipient@example.com"
    SmtpUser   = "username"
    SmtpPass   = "password"
    ConfigSet  = "Engagement"
    Host       = "email-smtp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com"
    Port       = 587
    Subject    = "Amazon SES Test (Gomail)"
    HtmlBody   = "<html><head><title>SES Sample Email</title></head><body>" +
        "<h1>Amazon SES Test Email (Gomail)</h1>" +
        "<p>This email was sent with " +
        "<a ses:tags='product:book;genre:fiction;subgenre:scifi;type:newrelease;'href='https://aws.amazon.com/ses/'>Amazon SES</a> using " +
        "the <a ses:tags='product:email;genre:test;subgenre:custom;type:gomail;'href='https://github.com/go-gomail/gomail/'>Gomail " +
        "package</a> for <a href='https://golang.org/'>Go</a>.</p>" +
        "</body></html>"

    TextBody = "This email was sent with Amazon SES using the Gomail package."
    Tags     = "genre=test,genre2=test2"
    CharSet  = "UTF-8"
)

func main() {

    m := gomail.NewMessage()
    m.SetBody("text/html", HtmlBody)
    m.AddAlternative("text/plain", TextBody)
    m.SetHeaders(map[string][]string{
        "From":                    {m.FormatAddress(Sender, SenderName)},
        "To":                      {Recipient},
        "Subject":                 {Subject},
        "X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET": {ConfigSet},
        "X-SES-MESSAGE-TAGS":      {Tags},
    })

    d := gomail.NewPlainDialer(Host, Port, SmtpUser, SmtpPass)
    if err := d.DialAndSend(m); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Email sent!")
    }
}
```

`click event`:

```py
In [29]: click_event['click']
Out[29]:
{'timestamp': '2021-02-26T10:44:00.606Z',
 'ipAddress': 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
 'userAgent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Safari/605.1.15',
 'link': 'https://aws.amazon.com/ses/',
 'linkTags': {'product': ['book'],
  'subgenre': ['scifi'],
  'genre': ['fiction'],
  'type': ['newrelease']}}

..

In [38]: click_event['mail']['tags']
Out[38]:
{'ses:operation': ['SendSmtpEmail'],
 'ses:configuration-set': ['Engagement'],
 'ses:source-ip': ['xx.xx.xx.xx'],
 'ses:from-domain': ['example.com'],
 'genre': ['test'],
 'genre2': ['test2'],
 'ses:caller-identity': ['ses-smtp-user']}
```

`open_event`

```py
In [41]: open_event1['mail']['tags']
Out[41]:
{'ses:operation': ['SendSmtpEmail'],
 'ses:configuration-set': ['Engagement'],
 'ses:source-ip': ['xx.xx.xx.xx'],
 'ses:from-domain': ['example.com'],
 'genre': ['test'],
 'genre2': ['test2'],
 'ses:caller-identity': ['ses-smtp-user']}
```

Received email:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I need those ses tags in the link of the received email in my mail box. It does not show up there. Also when I click on the link, I got an object from aws (updated in question). In that `linkTags` field is blank. Thats my problem.

Comment: @Amandeepkaur I updated the answer, it still works. You can use the direct sdk too if you want to send the email, I try to imitate the docs instead of building my own, but the idea still holds. I am getting the click events and corresponding tags too.